# Get Data from Google Form Spreadsheet (Android App Development)

Tags: android, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Eclipse to develop an app.

I used this code to submit data from my app to the Google Form.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyuJ2GtpZd0

I was wondering if you can help me with this: I need my app to read a column of data from the Google Form spreadsheet. I've tried looking everywhere for the code, but I can't seem to find it. Do you have any ideas how to implement this?

The column I want to read is a list of e-mails submitted from my app, and I just don't want the user to submit to my Google form multiple times!!! So, I need want to know how to read the list of emails from my Google Form.

I'm aware there is a Google Document API, but I'm not sure which part should I look at:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/?csw=1

Comment: Google spreadsheets api (google it)

Answer (score -1):

You can read data from Google Sheets using the [Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/). Depending on your use case you may want to use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) instead, since it provides a much simpler and more powerful way to ready data from Google Sheets.